# Load parts of page on demand without jquery

Tags: javascript, html, load

I am completely new to web design and I am experimenting with few things.

Lets assume that I can't use jquety and I can't upload any file to the page, instead I can use simple javascript.

What I have now is a table with few  tags, and a javascript function to show  based on checkboxes.

Script

```
 <script language="javascript">
function toggleTR(trId) {
    var trArray = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for(i = 0; i < trArray.length; i++){
        if(trArray[i].id == trId){
            if(trArray[i].style.display == 'none'){
                trArray[i].style.display = '';
            }else{
                trArray[i].style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" onClick="toggleTR('TR1');"/> TR1
```

And simple table

```
<table>
<tr id="TR1" style="display: none;">
<td>content</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

It works as intended, however as the page gets bigger the load time is horrible.

Is there a way for those  tags to be loaded on demand when display attribute is changed? I've read about lazy load, but could not get it to work with this.

Please try to explain it as easy as it could be, as I am totally inexperienced :-)

Comment: Since ID should be unique, you should use `document.getElementById()`

Comment: ID could be the same for many <tr>, but this is not the question here :-)

Comment: Oh yes it is. Since ID should be **unique** (as I said earlier) only 1 tr per Id should be in your HTML. Id = IDENTIFIER as always in programming.

Answer (score 0):

As ID should be unique, this should be more optimised

```
function toggleTR(trId) {
    var tr= document.getElementById(trId);
    if(tr != null){
        if(tr.style.display == 'none'){
            tr.style.display = '';
        }else{
            tr.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}
```

And if you don't want to hide/show **unique** element, then you can use classes.

```
<table>
<tr class="TR1" style="display: none;">
<td>content</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and

```
function toggleTR(trClass) {
    var tr= document.querySelectorAll('.'+trClass);
    if(tr != null){
        for(var i = 0, l = tr.length; i < l ; i++){
            if(tr[i].style.display == 'none'){
                tr[i].style.display = '';
            }else{
                tr[i].style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, now I know what you tried to tell me in a comment, still one question remains. Can I prevent the <tr> from loading till user use checkbox?

Comment: @wiktrollo then how are you going to load it later? ajax?

Comment: probably ajax. From what I read it would do, but I am still far away from being able to write it myself. Could you provide me with simple example based on previous data?
From what I read I would have to include required content inside a separate file and make a request for it. Is there an easy way? Could I for example load <td> with webparts on sharepoint?

Answer (score 0):

There can't be lazy load.
Your loop will keep on running till the end. Give a break statement if the id is found., so that the rest of th loop doesn't run.

```
    <script language="javascript">
    function toggleTR(trId) {
            var trArray = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
            for(i = 0; i < trArray.length; i++){
            if(trArray[i].id == trId){
                if(trArray[i].style.display == 'none'){
                    trArray[i].style.display = '';
                }else{
                    trArray[i].style.display = 'none';
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
```

OR
You can find the particular element by id and toggle as desired. This would be recommended though.

```
    var trobj = document.getElementById(trId);
    if (var != null)
    {
     // toggle code here
    }
```